# Laravel Eloquent Working with multiple tables of similar kind

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a database that was created for a legacy php application. I am importing this database into a new Laravel application.

This DB has 1900 table with same structure, column names and everything else just the tables have different names. But each tables has different data in it. To be specific each table belong a stock on an exchange and each stock has different data for high, low and closing price.

This tables have been copied from a single table called stock, duplicated using 'like' command in mysql.

My question is how can I import these database without creating 1900 migrations or models files.I have Researched on it extensively on the net but could find any questions even remotely similar.

Comment: You can create export and then import that database

Comment: Is your problem create all the files or something else?

Comment: yes, creating 1900 migrations and models is a problem but it also repetitive

Answer (score -1):

An option would be creating both a dynamic migration and a dynamic Model.

**Migration**

```
public function up()
{
    for ($i = 1; $i < 1900; $i++) {
        Schema::create('flights' . $i, function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('airline');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
}

public function down()
{
    for ($i = 1; $i < 1900; $i++) {
        Schema::drop('flights' . $i);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
class Flight extends Model
{
    //
    protected $table = 'my_flights';

    public function change_table(string $table) {
        $this->table = $table;
    }
}
```

Now you can change the corrosponding table on the fly, while keeping all the other attributes and functions of the model

Comment: Schema::create('flights' . $i,

Comment: This is disastrous..!

Comment: Yeah.. I know you gave the answer, but it's not a good solution. Read carefully, he said how can I import these database **without creating 1900 migrations**. I answered it with single Table and Model. Just tell me, is it right to create 1900 tables? That's why i said disastrous.

Comment: how would you pass a different name to each table in approach?

Answer (score -1):

This can be easily dealt with single table

Flights migration file

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('flights', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('airline');
        $table->string('stock_name'); // store stock name in this attribute
        $table->timestamps();
    });    
}

public function down()
{    
    Schema::drop('flights');    
}
```

Flight Model

```
class Flight extends Model
{        
    protected $table = 'flights';

    // Scope to find data from a particular stock
    public function scopeStock($q, $stockName)
    {
        return $q->where('stock_name', $stockName);
    }

}
```

Now you can search in any particular stock table like below

```
$stockName = 'flight1';
$data = Flight::stock($stockName)->get(); // search using the scope
//or
$data = Flight::where('stock_name', 'flight1')->get(); // or do a query
```

Simple and easy..! :)

Comment: why are you adding table name as column in the same table? how would you get each table with different name?

Comment: As you said, you have multiple stock tables, then you can store all the data from different tables in the single table and store the stock tablename to get the data from a particular stock table. I created a scope to get data easily from a particular stock. **$data = Flight::stock($stockTable)->get();**